# Facebook presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession never calls the handler

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

From Facebook tutorial on how to use share, there is a fallback to feed dialog, the call looks like below. The problem is that the handler is never called at all and nothing happens. Fresh SDK, empty test project.

```
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
              parameters:params
              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     // we never get here
}];
```

Comment: I got mine working, probably something in your params.  If you post your params I might be able to suggest a solution.